# Combine arbitrary number of columns into new table in R

Tags: r

I am reading a table which has 3n columns. Now I need to create new table which will have n+1 columns.

New format will be first column, followed by second divided by third column, followed by fifth divided by sixth column..

```
1.column 2./3. 5./6. 8./9. 11./12.
```

So that this:

```
a b c d e f g h i
```

will become

```
a b/c e/f h/i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cbind(df[, 1], df[, seq(from = 2, to = ncol(df), by = 3)] /
               df[, seq(from = 3, to = ncol(df), by = 3)])
```

Answer (score 0):

To make results obvious, here's an example `data.frame` filled with `i` in the `i`th column:

```
d <- data.frame(matrix(rep(1:9, each=5), 5))

#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9
# 1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
# 2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
# 3  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
# 4  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
# 5  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Now we'll take the first column, and then every column (3i-1) divided by column (3i) for i=1,2,... so the first one is (3-1)/(3), the second one is (6-1)/(6), etc. as you wanted. Here's one way to do that:

```
cbind(d[,1], do.call(cbind, lapply(1:(ncol(d)/3), function(i) d[,i*3-1]/d[,i*3])))
```

Either will produce:

```
#      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
# [1,]    1 0.6666667 0.8333333 0.8888889
# [2,]    1 0.6666667 0.8333333 0.8888889
# [3,]    1 0.6666667 0.8333333 0.8888889
# [4,]    1 0.6666667 0.8333333 0.8888889
# [5,]    1 0.6666667 0.8333333 0.8888889
```

which contain (1, 2/3, 5/6, 8/9) from the example matrix, verifying that it does what we wanted.